# Why the disk space on external hard drive of folder occupying which created by `create-react-app` command is so huge?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I just follow the instructions of [this page](https://create-react-app.dev/) but found the disk space of folder occupying via `create-react-app` command is intimidating 5GB!

[image: the folder size via create-react-app command is intimidating 5GB]
[[image: the folder size via create-react-app command is intimidating 5GB3]

But this action above was done on my external disk. I did the same action on my Built-in hard drive and found the disk space of newly created folder is only 244M.
[image]
**Why the difference is so huge and how to resolve it? I guess it is caused by disk fragmentation, but I googled it and it seems that the Mac does not need to be defragmented. My external disk is ExFAT format.**

Is this normal? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a heck of a lot of small files, your files average about 4kiB each (which is reasonable for source code and similar files)

exFat on large drives defaults to a 128kiB cluster size. This improves performamce with large files, but wastes a lot of space with small ones.

Unfortunately I dob't think you can reduce the cluster size without reformatting,

Comment: My God, It looks like I have to reformat it... Thank you very much...

Comment: I reformat my external disk, choose APFS format and everything is fine! Thank you again!